# XMEGA384C3 PORTA digital IO

Tags: avr

On the XMEGA384C3, is it possible to use PORT A and PORT B for General IO digital pins? On the datasheet it saids that the pins are for analog only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the XMEGA384C3, is it possible to use PORT A and PORT B for General IO digital pins?

Yes.

> On the datasheet it saids that the pins are for analog only.

You have misunderstood the [ATxmega384C3 datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8361-8-and-16-bit-AVR-XMEGA-Microcontrollers-ATxmega384C3_Datasheet.pdf) :-) However I can see how it could be interpreted the way you said e.g. the pinout diagram in section 2.

Pins on PORT A or PORT B can *optionally* be used for connections to the MCU ADC module (they are the only ports which can, optionally, be used for ADC measurements). That doesn't change the fact that those ports can also be used for standard, digital GPIO.

Comment: Thank you, do I have to do anything special to make them Digital GPIO?

Comment: No, nothing special needed to make them digital GPIO - they start that way after a reset. You *would* need to do special things to make them analog inputs to the ADC (e.g. configure the ADC registers for whichever pin(s) you want to be analog inputs, select single-ended or differential etc). If you do none of that, then PORT A & PORT B are digital GPIO ports like the others.